# php 7 session not returning values after header location

Tags: php, session

I am have upgrade php 7.0 from 5.3. Session below returns a value in php 5.3 but not php 7.0.

My php 7.0 is running on ubuntu 16.04 whereas php 5.3 is on ubuntu 12.04 server

**page1.php**

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr[];
session_write_close();
header("location: page2.php");
exit();
```

**page2.php**

```
    <?php 
         session_start();
         if( isset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && is_array($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) && count($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']) >0 ) 
     {
        foreach($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] as $msg) 
        {
            echo "<font color='red' size='2'>" . $msg . "</font><br>"; 
        }
    }
    unset($_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR']);
?>
```

Does php 7.0 having some issues with sessions?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to find the simple solution. Its my bad. PHP 7.0 requires a

```
<?php instead of <?
```

My bad.